# ZF2 - How to use SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS in columns()

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I'm trying to use **SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS** in my query. But I can't create my query without **AS Expression1**

```
$select = $this->getSql()->select();
            $select->columns(array("*", new Expression(" SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *")));
            $select->join( array ( 
                    'c2h' => 'site_category2help_topic' ), 'c2h.help_topic_id = site_help_topic.help_topic_id', array ( 
                    "*" ) );
            $select->where( " c2h.category_id = $categoryId " );
            $select->limit($limit);
            $select->offset($offset);
```

**RESULT:**

```
SELECT site_help_topic.*, SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * *AS Expression1*, c2h.* 

FROM site_help_topic 

INNER JOIN site_category2help_topic AS c2h 

ON c2h.help_topic_id = site_help_topic.help_topic_id 

WHERE c2h.category_id = 5 LIMIT '15' OFFSET '0'
```

**IT SHOULD BE :**

```
SELECT site_help_topic.*, SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *, c2h.* 

FROM site_help_topic 

INNER JOIN site_category2help_topic AS c2h 

ON c2h.help_topic_id = site_help_topic.help_topic_id 

WHERE c2h.category_id = 5 LIMIT '15' OFFSET '0'
```

Comment: You hit the nail on the head, Expression will always add in 'AS XXX' if not already there, you will need to do a raw query :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sql\Select has an option `QUANTIFIER`, you should be able to use that instead of giving it as a column name.

Similar to here [How to use SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS with Zend\Db\TableGateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14156151/who-to-use-sql-calc-found-rows-with-zend-db-tablegateway)